# Problem in show doc file

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, doc

I have a doc file with picture and table and want to show it in C# form. when i load it in richtextbox the table is not showing correctly

how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: You have to be more detailed. What GUI library are you using? WinForms, WPF or something else? How do you load the doc in richtextbox? What do you expect to see and what do you actually see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A real doc file much more than rtf which is the format the richtextbox understands.

IF you really need to display (perhaps edit or convert to PDF...) a doc file then you will need to use some 3rd-party component like Aspose.Words...

Another option - although only for desktop applications and requiring Word to be installed would be to use Office Automation - see

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264733.aspx
[C# office 2010 automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510295/c-office-2010-automation)
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/ms_office_automation.aspx